# Redirect to SSL only if browser supports SNI

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, sni

I have Apache 2.2 with mod_ssl and a bunch of sites in HTTPS on the same IP/port with VirtualHosting, so client must support SNI to connect to those virtual hosts.

I would like to configure my server the following way:

When a user types www.dummysite.com and his browser **supports** SNI (Server Name Indication), any HTTP request is redirected to `https://` where an HSTS header is sent. But if the browser **doesn't support** SNI then the request is served by HTTP.

The above rule, stated as is, is actually a fallback rule for those people that still run old browsers, as Mozilla and Chrome don't have this problem, just to avoid leaving these users out of the site.

I would like to do this redirecting at the Apache config level, perhaps with a filter on the user agent. I wouldn't like to touch running applications except making sure that no direct http:// references are present (otherwise they imply a security warning)

[Edit] (while editing the question I forgot **the** question): what is the list of SNI-enabled user agents to redirect?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since SNI occurs during the SSL/TLS handshake, it's not possible to detect browser support when the client connects to HTTP.

So, you're right; a user-agent filter is the only way to do this.

The big question is whether you want to act on a blacklist against browsers that you know won't listen for SNI, or a whitelist of browsers that are known to support it.  Obscure or new devices being unable to use the site seems like a deal-breaker, so I'd say the whitelist might be the better option.

In your HTTP `<VirtualHost>`:

```
# Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9, on Vista or newer
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s7.*Windows\sNT\s6 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s8.*Windows\sNT\s6 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s9.*Windows\sNT\s6 [OR]
# Chrome on Windows, Mac, Linux
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\sNT\s6.*Chrome [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Macintosh.*Chrome [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Linux.*Chrome [OR]
# Firefox - we'll just make the assumption that all versions in the wild support:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Gecko.*Firefox
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://ssl.hostname/$1 [R=301]
```

Here's the blacklist option, too - keep in mind that this runs the risk of sending a client that doesn't use SNI to an SNI-needed site, but on the other hand, will send users of something new like IE 10 to the right place:

```
# IE 6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
# Windows XP/2003
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Windows\sNT\s5
# etc etc
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://ssl.hostname/$1 [R=301]
```

There are a lot of browsers out there.  I've been pretty loose with the expressions and haven't covered a lot of browsers - this could turn into quite the nightmare to maintain.

Whichever option you choose.. good luck!

Comment: Great! I tested with Opera Mobile (which is SNI compliant but not in the list) and it doesn't redirect. With my Firefox, it does redirect!

Comment: I suggest modularizing this solution with the BrowserMatch directive from mod_setenvif http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html .  Use BrowserMatch to set an environment variable supports_sni=y, then write RewriteCond %{ENV:supports_sni} =y.  That way, you can reuse the SNI detection logic for any other RewriteRules that you might have.

Comment: @200_success Good idea!

Answer (score 9):

My solution is this:

```
  # Test if SNI will work and if not redirect to too old browser page
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_TLS_SNI} =""
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/too-old-browser [L,R=307]
```

If an old browser without SNI tries to access https://www.example.com/* then it will throw a error on the browser first, which cannot be avoided since until apache replies to a non-SNI browser it doesn't know which site it is asking for.  Then it redirects to a page telling the user their browser is too old (as long as user clicks continue to website).

And for users with new browsers I have

```
  #Test if new browser and if so redirect to https
  #new browser is not MSIE 5-8, not Android 0-3
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\ [5-8]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Android.*(Mobile)?\ [0-3]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That excludes most of the old browsers, including some like MSIE 5-8 on Vista (9+ is only Vista/7 so supports SNI). It's not 100% (symbian is ignored etc.) but should work for the majority.  The minority can still choose to accept the certificate error.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware there's not really a good way to do this -- You can use a [mod_rewrite rule](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) or similar [conditionally](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) based on the `User-agent` header, but it would have to be on a NON-SSL vhost: If the browser *does not* support SNI and it goes to a secure (`https://`) site it's going to get the old-school Apache behavior of ["Here's the first SSL certificate I have associated with that IP address -- Hope it's what you wanted!"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2) -- If that's not the certificate the browser was expecting you'll wind up with an error message about hostname mismatches.

This basically means people have to hit a non-SSL interstitial page that will redirect them - possibly exposing any data they're sending in their request.  This may or may not be a deal breaker (you say you're going to send them to a non-SSL site anyway if they don't support SNI, so I assume you don't care that much about security.  If I were designing a system that had a need for SSL as an encryption or authentication layer I'd be a bit more insistent about it though...)

None of that stops someone from bookmarking the secure site though - and if they use a shared bookmark service or restore their bookmarks to a machine where the web browser doesn't support SNI they're back in the Potential-for-SSL-Errors case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to solve this one of three ways:

1. `RewriteRule` based on `User-Agent` headers.
2. Load a https:// URI in a `<SCRIPT>` tag on a non-default VHost; if the load succeeds, it's a bit of JS that reloads the whole page under HTTPS.
3. Teach my visitors to use something like HTTPS Everywhere if this is a priority for them, force HTTPS on pages where it should be required, and hope everything works out in the end.

Of these, I personally like #2 the best, but that involves modifying your sites' code.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone needing it.

If you have multiple hosts and want all them to be SSL-enabled in VirtualHosting (and you bought a certificate for each) try the new `mod_djechelon_ssl`

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/mod_djechelon_ssl.conf 
RewriteEngine on
# Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9, on Vista or newer
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s7.*Windows\sNT\s6 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s8.*Windows\sNT\s6 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s9.*Windows\sNT\s6 [OR]
# Chrome on Windows, Mac, Linux
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\sNT\s6.*Chrome [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Macintosh.*Chrome [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Linux.*Chrome [OR]
# Firefox - we'll just make the assumption that all versions in the wild support:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Gecko.*Firefox [OR]
#Safari iThing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mozilla.*iPhone.*Safari [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mozilla.*iPod.*Safari [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mozilla.*iPad.*Safari [OR]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Usage:

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
ServerName www.yourhost.com

Include /path/to/mod_djechelon_ssl.conf

[plain old Apache directives]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip:443>
ServerName www.yourhost.com

[SSL-related directives]

[Copy and paste directives from above host]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

[As I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39341229/195835), you can only test for SNI support *prior* to requiring it. That is, you cannot force users onto SNI HTTPS and then fall-back if they don't support it, because they will receive an error like this (from Chrome on Windows XP) with no way to proceed.

[image]

So (unfortunately) the user has to actually begin over an insecure HTTP connection and then be upgraded only if they support SNI.

You can detect SNI support via:

1. **Remote script**
   From your plain HTTP page, load a `<script>` from your destination SNI HTTPS server and if the script loads and runs correctly, you know the browser supports SNI.
2. **Cross-Domain AJAX (CORS)**
   Similar to option 1, you could try performing a cross-domain AJAX request from the HTTP page to the HTTPS, but be aware that CORS has [only limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors).
3. **Sniff the user-agent**
   This is probably the least reliable method, and you will need to decide between having a blacklist of browsers (and operating systems) known not to support it, or a whitelist of known systems that do.

   We know that all versions of IE, Chrome & Opera on Windows XP and below do not support SNI. See [CanIUse.com for full list of supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sni).